# How can I send http messages from android app( physical device) to my local server without using internet connection?

Tags: android

I have an app that runs in an emulator. The app sends multiple messages to my local server, for manipulating data. While i was using the app in my emulator i was using:

```
http://10.0.2.2/path
```

to reach the server. I would like to use a physical device to connect to the server. Does somebody know how to do this. What adress i should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your devices are on the same Network (connected to the same router) as your computer, you can expose your computer's web server (Apache, presumably?) and then point your app directly at the local network IP address that your computer has (usually something like 192.168.1.x).  I have found that the least painless way to do this is to use MAMP or WAMP or LAMP depending on your OS, but of course I have no idea what your specific situation is, so that solution may in fact make things a lot more complicated rather than less.

In any event... your computer is on the network at a specific IP address, so it's just a matter of making sure that it's willing to serve this data on whatever port you are looking for it on.  If you provide more specification as to your circumstances, we can give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Well i am using windows, and apache server, actually XAMPP. Yes the devices are connected under the same router. How can i get the local ip of the computer on which the server is running?